# Two fonts in the same sentence

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, how do I make labels consist of two parts, one of which is in regular text, and the other is in boldface? It's only easy to set a font for an entire sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using gnuplot 5 it is quite easy.  In `enhanced` text mode, which is by default switched on, you can use the syntax `{/:Bold ...}` to select the boldface of whatever font is currently select. Likewise, using `{/:Normal ...}` and `{/:Italic ...}` selects normal or italic font styles:

```
set label 1 center at 0,0 '{/:Bold bold {/:Normal normal} {/:Italic bold italic}} {/:Italic italic}' font 'Linux Biolinum O,20'
plot x
```

[image]