# set different fonts for legends in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, legend

In gnuplot, I want to set different fonts to the legends, one legend in Italic, the other one in Times Roman. If I use set font, it will apply to all legends. What should I do?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20038368/gnuplot-italics-in-a-portion-of-a-label?rq=1) may be helpful. Taken from the links provided by SO on the right hand side of your post.

Comment: @vaettchen Yes, this is the correct way. The correct syntax for gnuplot 5 is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31285311/2604213)

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well.